# Error while updating multiple objects using Django rest_framework serializers

Tags: django, django-models, django-rest-framework, django-views, django-serializer

I am making API for an order which can have multiple foods. I am able to create it successfully but when I try to update with food id, I am getting an error like NoneType object has no attribute 'get'.

Here is my code:

models.py

```
class Order(models.Model):
    order_no = models.PositiveIntegerField(blank=True,null=True)

class VegFood(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=25,blank=True,null=True)
    price = models.CharField(max_length=25,blank=True,null=True)
    order = models.ForeignKey(Order,on_delete=models.CASCADE,blank=True,null=True,related_name="order")
```

serializers.py

```
class VegFoodSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = VegFood
        fields = ['name','price']
```

```
class OrderSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    """
    for multiple add items importinf serializers in Order
    """
    veg_foods = VegFoodSerializer(many=True,required=False)
    nonveg_foods = NonVegFoodSerializer(many=True,required=False)
    starters = StarterSerializer(many=True,required=False)
    deserts = DesertSerializer(many=True,required=False)

    class Meta:
        model = Order
        fields = ['order_no','veg_foods','nonveg_foods','starters','deserts']

    def create(self, validated_data):
        veg_food_validated_data = validated_data.pop('veg_foods',None)

        if veg_food_validated_data:
            for veg_food in veg_food_validated_data:
                veg_food_obj = VegFood.objects.create(order=orders,**veg_food)

        return orders

    def update(self, instance, validated_data):
        instance.order_no = validated_data.pop('order_no', instance.order_no)
        veg_food_validated_data = validated_data.pop('veg_foods',None)
        if veg_food_validated_data:
            for veg_food in veg_food_validated_data:
                veg_food_id = veg_food.get('veg_food_id')
                print(veg_food_id)
                veg_foods, created = VegFood.objects.get_or_create(order_id=instance.id,id=veg_food_id)
                veg_foods.name = veg_food_id.get('name',None)
                veg_foods.price = veg_food_id.get('price',None)
                veg_foods.save()
        instance.save()
        return instance
```

My JSON body is :

```
{
  "order_no":1,
  "veg_foods":[
          {
            "veg_food_id":1,
            "name":curry1,
            "price":150
          },
          {
            "veg_food_id":2,
            "name":curry2,
            "price":120
          },
          {
            "name":curry2,
            "price":120
          }
    ]
}
```

So object1 & object2 I am passing id so it will update 1st & 2nd object. Object 3 doesn't have id so it will create the 3rd object. But I am getting error something like this:

> NoneType object has no attribute 'get'.

What mistake am I doing?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is here:

```
veg_food_id = veg_food.get('veg_food_id')
veg_foods.name = veg_food_id.get('name',None)
```

Where you've already said for that third object `veg_food.get('veg_food_id')` is `None`. The error you're getting makes sense. Instead, you should use `veg_food.get('name')` or handle it as such with `update_or_create`.

```
veg_food_id = veg_food.pop('veg_food_id', None)
veg_foods, created = VegFood.objects.update_or_create(order_id=instance.id, id=veg_food_id, defaults=veg_food)
```

Comment: The problem in this approach is it is creating new VegFood objects instead of updating it when I pass 'veg_food_id'  in body , ex : {
            "veg_food_id":1,
            "name":curry1,
            "price":150
          },
          {
            "veg_food_id":2,
            "name":curry2,
            "price":120
          } , in this case it is creating new objects instead of updating it based on  veg_food_id.